Using the C preprocessor, how to warn only once on macro usage?
I would like to display a warning message when the user calls a macro, but only once per compilation unit, so they don't drown in error messages.
Something like that:
int main() {
  MACRO(42); // <- a preprocessor warning should be displayed here
  MACRO(42); // <- but not here
  return 0;
}

I'm currently using _Pragma(message \"...\") to display a warning on MACRO usage, but it is displayed every time.

I'm not sure which compiler you are using but look for the #pragma warning statement. In the Microsoft preprocessor there is an option to display a message once only.

@OldBoy That would only help for the definition, not at useage, because it cannot be used inside a macro. Also not only once as far as I know.

@Yunnosch Qjuite possibly; but we have no idea what these macros are actually doing.
